# When I use VPN what is the route to access to Internet?

Tags: networking, internet, vpn

Probably this question is so simple.

Sometimes I have to use a VPN to connect some of my clients.

If I have the VPN with a client, my internet traffic pass from the VPN's (network) client ?

Comment: What do you want it to be?  You get to choose.  (Assuming this isn't some corporate VPN pushed to your system).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking...

When you setup a VPN connection, say connecting to some client's VPN server, you essentially have a point to point "tunnel" from your system to the client's machine. All network traffic (normally) would go over that tunnel. So yes, access to the Internet would go across the tunnel to the client's machine, and out from there to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

This depends. If you only have a tunnel (e.g. you are creating a secure tunnel between two machines over internet) your internet should go as normal. If you are bridging ethernets (you connect to remote LAN and receive address of remote subnet and see all computers) you will probably "get internet over internet".

You can always find out by using Traceroute (tracert on Windows)